# Why does standalone truncate my tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-cd, bounding-box

While I was testing [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338739/101651) of mine, I realized I had to set the standalone border option to `border={2mm 2mm 14mm 2mm}` because simply with `border=2mm` the image was truncated.

Why?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
%\documentclass[tikz, border={2mm 2mm 14mm 2mm}]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}% 
        &[-30pt] \ker(f) \arrow[dl, phantom, sloped, "\supset"] \arrow[dr, phantom, sloped, "\subset"]&[-30pt] & &[-75pt] \\[-4pt]
        \ker(w) \arrow[rr, phantom, "\subset"]& & E \arrow[rr, "w"] \arrow[rd, end anchor={[xshift=.5em]north west}, "\pi_f"] \arrow[dd, swap, "f"] & & \mathbb{K}\\
        & & & E/\ker(f) \simeq Im(f) \arrow[ru, dashrightarrow, start anchor={[xshift=1.1em]north west}, swap, "w'"]& \\
        & & F & & 
    \end{tikzcd}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The bounding box appears to be computed incorrectly. Possibly because of the `[-75pt]`

Comment: @egreg It's that, of course, but it's necessary, otherwise I don't get the desidered alignment. Thank you!

Comment: You should use `\mathllap`/`\mathclap`/`\mathrlap` instead of playing with global settings. Voss's `Mathmode.pdf` has an example regarding `∑_{something too long}`.

Comment: By the way: **The au­thor con­sid­ers this pack­age now as be­ing too old and af­flicted with too many ty­po­graph­i­cal bugs. That’s why it has been clas­si­fied as “ob­so­lete”, at least for the time be­ing.**

Comment: @Symbol1 I'll study Voss's `Mathmode.pdf`, thank you! Where is it written that tikz-cd is obsolete? I've found no news googling around...

Comment: Oops, I meant `Mathmode.pdf` is obsolete, according to [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode)

Comment: @Symbol1 Ah, OK, I've misunderstood, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer combining several tricks:

- define new styles for subsets/supersets
- use `\mathrlap` for overlay part

  - use `\mathord` to control the spacing before `\mathrlap`
  - `Im` should be `\operatorname{Im}`.
- usage of `column sep=` to avoid the diagram being too wide.

  - add additional `&` to create spaces on the right. (This is dirty!)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \tikzcdset{
        subset/.code={\tikzcdset{double line}\pgfsetarrows{Arc Barb[length=0 .5].-}},
        supset/.code={\tikzcdset{double line}\pgfsetarrows{-.Arc Barb[length=0 .5]}}
    }
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny]
        & \ker(f) \dlar[subset] \drar[subset] &&& \\
        \ker(w) \ar[rr,subset]& & E \ar[rr, "w"] \drar["\pi_f"] \arrow[dd,',"f"] && \mathbb{K} \\
        &&& E/\ker(f)\mathrlap{\mathord{}\simeq Im(f)} \urar[dashrightarrow,',"w'"]& \\
        && F &&&&
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This can be an answer also of the [original question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338716/how-to-make-a-good-diagram-arrow/338739#338739). Great `subset` and `supset` but I think mine are more clearly visible.

Comment: nice solution, but it is difficult to recognize `\subset`s relation between top left nodes ...

Comment: @Zarko Then one needs to use, for example,`double distance between line centers=1.3ex`.